# Extracting numerical coefficients from an expression

Tags: pattern-matching, expression-manipulation, filtering

I have very large expression and I want to extract and sum up all the numerical coefficients which multiply the summands.

For example,

```
expr = x + 2*y + 3*z*w
```

What I need is for *Mathematica* to do is to extract the numerical coefficients `{1, 2, 3}` and sum them up, `1+2+3=6`.

I cannot use `Coefficient` function, because the expressions (represented by `x`, `y`, `z` and `w` in the above example) are very complicated, and the summation is huge.

Does anyone have any suggestions how to solve this? Thank you.

Comment: Maybe you could provide an example of one of the complex expressions you mentioned? This would help in finding a solution, which might really fit your needs.

Comment: BTW, Welcome to Mathematica.SE! I suggest the following: 1) As you receive help, try to give it too, by answering questions in your area of expertise. 2) Read the [faq](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/tour)! 3) When you see good questions and answers, vote them up by [clicking the gray triangles](http://i.stack.imgur.com/eNrdG.png), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge. Also, please remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, by [clicking the checkmark sign](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/)!

Answer (score 3):

Ditto what Kuba said about details.  Another guess:

```
expr /. Thread[Variables[expr] -> 1]
(*  6  *)
```

I guess it works for polynomials.  It's not really clear to me what the coefficients of `Exp[x]` are.  (It might be `1 Exp[1 x]`, etc.)  Or `(x + y)^2` vs. `x^2 + 2 x y + y^2`.  (This answer gives the sum of the coefficients of the latter.)

---

Another interpretation, assuming `expr` has the head `Plus`:

```
coeff[term_Times] := Times @@ Cases[term, _?NumericQ];
coeff[term_?NumericQ] := term;
coeff[term_] := 1;

coeff /@ expr
(*  6  *)

coeff /@ (3 - x^2 + 2 Sqrt[2] x y - Sin[2] Sin[z] + (x + y)^2)
(*  3 + 2 Sqrt[2] - Sin[2]  *)
```

Note in this interpretation `(x + y)^2` is treated as an atomic term with coefficient `1`.

Comment: It works quite nice, I wasn't aware what can be taken as *variable*. +1

Comment: Do you know why `Variables /@ {Sin[x], Exp[x]}`?

Comment: @Kuba `Variables` works well on polynomials.  I guess `Sin[_]` and `Cos[_]` are considered "variables."  I suppose for trig. equations.

Comment: This works like a charm, thanks a lot!

Comment: @Luka  You're welcome. Out of curiosity, which one?

Answer (score 2):

It is quite possible that details matter. Without those, we can only guess what could be useful:

```
Cases[expr, x_. y___ :> x, {1}] (*{1} is redundant, just wanted to stress it out *)
% // Total
```

> ```
> {1, 2, 3}
>  6
> ```

Comment: Ahhh! I edited the wrong post!! So sorry!

Comment: @MichaelE2 No problem ;)